# json array parse return nil in swift 5

Tags: swift

I have an json. In json there is multiple array. Here is my json...

```
 ["city": imrankhan136260@gmail.com, 
"geofence_DEMRAhighway": {"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates":[[[90.45232332650568,23.714463300877014],[90.4532990923671,23.712264209703946],[90.45997933551394,23.714532021878767]]]}]
```

I have use bellow code get data ,it returns correct value

```
   let city = myjson?["city"] as? String
    print("city-->",city) // it returns imrankhan136260@gmail.com
```

But when it use bellow code get from **geofence_DEMRAhighway** key which returns nil. here is my code to get array

```
 let geofence_BABUBAZARbridge = myjson?["geofence_BABUBAZARbridge"] as? [String: Any]
```

What is the wrong with the code. please help me  to parse the json

Comment: The second key `geofence_BABUBAZARbridge` is simply different than the key in the original JSON. Additionally, the JSON itself is not valid. Can you double-check?

Comment: here is some part of json: Optional(["city": imrankhan136260@gmail.com, "geofence_BABUBAZARbridge": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813],[90.4018551231959,23.708188760430843],[90.40247361862504,23.7091957460091],[90.40143983815886,23.70975584674032],[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813]]]}, "image": xiOHhaFfBXaMHewCwznPjejMPWrle48KEiDh75eh.png, "garage": 23.760297460136112;90.41100695643615;357/19/A/1, Modhubug 1 No. Goli, Mogbazar, ????, ???? ?????, ????????, "last_name": Khan, "address2": , "mob2": , "address3":

Comment: @fatih it is big json , i just give you small part : here is my small part json :Optional(["city": imrankhan136260@gmail.com, "geofence_BABUBAZARbridge": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813],[90.4018551231959,23.708188760430843],[90.40247361862504,23.7091957460091],[90.40143983815886,23.70975584674032],[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813]]]},

Comment: Are you sure the full format of the JSON is like this? non-number and boolean values should be wrapped with a string identifier. If this doesn't help, you can also check if there are non-string booleans. Depending on them being capitalized, they might cause some issues.

Comment: @fatih thanks i have received data from a api whch provide me like that.

Comment: Oh, I see, this is possibly from console output. Why are you reading `geofence_BABUBAZARbridge` as a string? I think it should be JSON or a dictionary.

Comment: @fatih I have string data like {"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813],[90.4018551231959,23.708188760430843],[90.40247361862504,23.7091957460091],[90.40143983815886,23.70975584674032],[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813]]]}

Comment: @EnamulHaque did you ever get a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This json is not filly correct.

It's starts from "[", but usualy {...} uses to map it to asociative array.

But if it works, you can still use it.

So, coordinates is not a string. You have to escape it, and it will see as

```
 {\"type\": \"Polygon\",\r\n\"coordinates\":[[[90.45232332650568,23.714463300877014],[90.4532990923671,23.712264209703946],[90.45997933551394,23.714532021878767]]]}
```

If you can not change the format, then you shoud read it as JSonObject and convert it to string:

```
JSONSerialization.jsonObject(.....)
```

And then use

```
myjson?["city"]["type"]
```

You can try this:

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: myjson?["city"], options: [])
```

myjson?["city"] will return an object, and JSONSerialization.data will convert it to string

And so one.

Comment: is it possible {"type": "Polygon","coordinates":[[[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813],[90.4018551231959,23.708188760430843],[90.40247361862504,23.7091957460091],[90.40143983815886,23.70975584674032],[90.40082675305842,23.708825220302813]]]}